# removing corrupted files using a bash script

Tags: bash, find, grep

I have many "bad" files after recover my broken hdd.

I need script in bash which helps me remove bad files like

- zero byte consists only (00 00 00 00 00 ...)

Comment: You can use `cmp filename /dev/zero`. If the file consists of all null bytes, "EOF" will be included in the output to stderr, if there are any non-null bytes, "differ" will be included in the output to stderr (based on GNU `cmp`).

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use `find`:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -empty -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f -v
```

Comment: Except that a file filled with nulls is not empty. Also, see `-exec` and `-delete`.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -size 0c -maxdepth 1 -exec rm {} \;
```

How about this?

Comment: find . -type f -size 0 -exec rm {} \; | awk '{ print $8 }'  -- remove zero size files, and it's Ok. What about detect zero-bytes-filled files?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `rm \{\}`? Or perhaps that's a `zsh` thing...

Comment: @Borealid It works fine in bash.