# find and remove all closed files that are not modified in some-time

Tags: linux, find, filesystems

I'm building a script in linux that will remove files from the disc that aren't in used currently by the OS. I want to use find command so I can execute rm for all the files that I find that are not open.
I tried so far this command without success:

```
find /folderToSearch/ -type f | while read filename ; do /sbin/fuser -s $filename || echo $filename ; done
```

I found this command in some website it supposed to print all files that are not in used. Although when I open using 'vi' command concurrently to find it still printing the filename.

Comment: check all emty files then delete `find -maxdepth 1 -type f -empty -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f -v` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044481/removing-corrupted-files-using-a-bash-script

Comment: i'm not looking for deleting empty files. I'm looking for deleting files that are NOT open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the list of open files you can use `lsof` command. Get all the list of files from `find` command in a directory and remove them all.

1). Get the list of open files in a directory.

```
lsof /folderToSearch |awk '{print $NF}'|sed -e '1 d' |sort |uniq >/tmp/lsof
```

2). Get the list of files in a directory.

```
find /folderToSearch -type f -print >/tmp/find
```

3). Remove the `/tmp/lsof` list from `/tmp/find` file and then remove them.

```
grep -v  -w -f /tmp/lsof /tmp/find |xargs rm -f
```

Comment: I think there is a problem with the deletion

Comment: i have a file name todelete.txt that isn't deleted after running this script:

Comment: #! /bin/bash

lsof /ccview/YitzhakOs/test | awk '{print $NF}'|sed -e '1 d' | sort | uniq > /ccview/YitzhakOs/test/tmp/lsof
find /ccview/YitzhakOs/test -type f -print > /ccview/YitzhakOs/test/tmp/find
grep -v  -w -f /ccview/YitzhakOs/test/tmp/lsof /ccview/YitzhakOs/test/tmp/find | xargs rm -f

Comment: Can you see that file in `/ccview/YitzhakOs/test/tmp/find `  ?

Comment: Is other files are getting removed ?